# RIA Services / EF. Changes to bool field in a derived class are not saving to database

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

We are using EF with RIA services.  A simple application. Load a list of items, browse/edit/save.
The problem is that some of the changes are not persisting to the db.

I have a model with the following

```
Person
   ...
   string Name
   bool IsActive


Customer : Person
   ...
   string Address
   bool IsLocal
```

Changes made to a Person save correctly.

When changing a Customer, if I change the **IsLocal** value to true, it saves correctly. If I change it to false, the change is not persisted to the database.

1. Boiler plate generated code, no customizations
2. No error messages. As far as the submit op is concerned, all went well.
3. Changes to Address save correctly

   - If I change the Address and set IsLocal, both save correctly.
   - If I change the Address and clear IsLocal, the address saves but IsLocal stays set.
4. Changes to IsActive (in Person) always save correctly, whether clearing or setting.
5. I have recreated the problem in another solution with different tables.

   - Seems to be the same problem, cannot clear bool/bit field in a derived class.

Any help that people can offer would be appreciated. 
Thanks, 
Alan.

Comment: Did you get any help on this question?  I just fell victim to the same thing.

Comment: No. Answer back. One of the other developers here has been following it up. The EF people say that it's not happening on their side and the he hasn't received anything back from the RIA people.  We are using Stored Procedures as a workaround at the moment.

Comment: Can you post the generated client-side RIA file source?

Comment: Any more updates on this? I just spent a day trying to figure this out. I found out that if I set the RoundtripToOriginal attribute on the base class, everything works fine but I don't think this is optimum...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got a solution that is working for me...

I replaced the generated code for the **Update** method from:

```
this.ChangeSet.AttachAsModified( entity, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal( entity ) );
```

for

```
this.ChangeSet.Attach( entity );
this.ObjectContext.ChangeObjectState( entity, EntityState.Modified );
```

Hope this helps!